# My copy of Snailplane's comment was deleted

Tags: discussion

I just want to know why so I know when I'd be able to do or never again.

WendiKidd has deleted the copy of Snailplane's comment I added into my post as an update
https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/16049/revisions

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but afaict revising the question itself is preferred over adding information with "Edit" or "Update" appendices. Another reason might be snailplane's comment can still be found below. Imho, adding a note (without saying Edit or Update) by rephrasing what snailplane said as *"According to snailplane's comment below, ..."* might be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer directly into the question makes the question kind of pointless... it's better to let the comment-posters convert their comments to answers if they can be convinced the comments are worthy.

Also, adding a "suggested answer" into the question may "taint the recall", as it were, of other would-be answerers; by which I mean you've predisposed them to think of the answer you've given rather than coming up with other answers on their own.

Comment: I see why now; thanks. As far as I know, snailplate is not usually inclined to give formal answers and prefers comments, and by the way in this very case I was satisfied so that's why I added the answer in so I can refer to it when needed. There must be a practical solution because leaving good comments buried in the post does not seem right. How about summarize/paraphrase a buried comment into an answer?

Comment: @learner If you think a commenter provided you a complete answer, and nobody else did, respond to the commenter asking them to post it as an answer. If there's no response in a reasonable period of time, answer it yourself, giving the commenter whatever credit seems appropriate.

Comment: @learner In this case, I did (attempt to) answer the question.  The comment you're referring to was an answer to a follow-on question you asked in another comment.