# If there is more than one right answer can I summarize the answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

If there is more than one right answer to a question can I accept one and summarize the answers under the question description with an edit note?

For example, a previous question I asked: [What is the correct word for "turn off lamp" for a non-electric lamp?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133768/what-is-the-correct-word-for-turn-off-lamp) got more than one right answer. It's not technically possible for me to accept them all. I have up-voted all the right answers. Is it okay to just summarize the right answers by editing the question?

Comment: Here is a related discussion where adding part of an answer into the question caused some confusion: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/922/ I thought some of the explanations about what that wasn't a good idea were relevant to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [As a learner, how do I choose which answer to accept?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3421/) discussion might help a little. If you truly can't decide among all the answers which one helped you the most, you don't have to accept one at all. You've already up-voted the ones that you found useful, and that's the best way to express your appreciation in the StackExchange model :)

Questions should not contain answers, and answers shouldn't contain questions. By attempting to summarize the answers at a particular point in time, you're making your question more static than it should be, and removing valuable information like the community scores and comments on those answers.

Often new answers will come in months after a question was asked and those answers might be more helpful than the original answers, or maybe an author of an existing answer will come back later and improve their answer. Every time that happened someone would have to update the summary to reflect the current state of the question. It would add a lot of work and I don't see what value it would add.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should **leave the question as the question** instead of placing an answer in the question box, or pointing to an answer from the question box.

The green tick doesn't necessarily specify the *only* answer, or indeed the *best* answer objectively. It's the answer that is *most helpful* to the person who asked the question (i.e. 'best' to you).

> The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.
>   [- meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/286574)

As such, up-vote all the answers that have been useful to you, and tick the one that you like best in terms of answering your question. If you think some of the other answers deserve a mention, you can leave a comment under your question, or under the accepted answer, that mentions them or links to them (or both).